# Vue.js v-for with dynamic names

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to get my component to accept json data, where I won't know in advance the name of the array or the field names

For instance if it's

```
 "user": [  
      {
        "id": "1",
        "userid": "asdad@asd.dsfsdf",
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "userid": "sdfsdf@asd.sdf",
        "name": "Trev"
      }
 ]
```

I'll also pass in some meta, that will specify the name and the fields.
e.g.

```
{
   name: 'user',
   columns: [
    "userid",
    "name"
  ]
}
```

If I hard code it 
e.g.

```
<tr v-for="row in IncomingData.user">
    <td>{{ row.userid }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

It works, but I don't want to hard code.
I've tried to see if I can specify the v-for using a string
e.g.

```
   <tr v-for="row in eval('IncomingData.user')">
```

But this does not work.
How can I specify the names of things dynamically in vue.js templates

Comment: You can loop through Object.keys in v-for so it doesn't matter what is the name of the properties... (of course, it works only with a flat Object with primitive values only, not with Objects or Arrays).

Comment: You may also use `IncomingData[varName]` where `varName` is dynamic name you want to use (e.g `user` or anything else).

Comment: @Igor you've really helped. If you add this as an answer I'll mark as solved

Comment: No problem, I've added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `IncomingData[varName]` where `varName` is dynamic name you want to use (e.g `user` or anything else).

Answer (score 1):

If there is multiple elements lets say `users`,'others' you can use another outer loop

```
<template v-for="inner in IncomingData">
    <tr v-for="row in inner">
        <td>{{ row.userid }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

If there is only one element lets say `users` and you just want to get first unknown key, then use

```
    <tr v-for="row in IncomingData[Object.keys(IncomingData)[0]]">
        <td>{{ row.userid }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
    </tr>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
  IncomingData:{
    "user": [  {
        "id": "1",
        "userid": "asdad@asd.dsfsdf",
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "userid": "sdfsdf@asd.sdf",
        "name": "Trev"
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

By Inner Loop
<table width="100%">
<tr style="text-align:left;">
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<template v-for="inner in IncomingData">
    <tr v-for="row in inner">
        <td>{{ row.userid }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
</table>
<br/><br/>
By getting first key name
<table width="100%">
<tr style="text-align:left;">
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr v-for="row in IncomingData[Object.keys(IncomingData)[0]]">
    <td>{{ row.userid }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to post. But Igor's comment and subsequent answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: that fine, there is always has other way to do one thing